# Animate a lattice with Python

Tags: python, animation, lattice

Fellowing instructions found in a [youtube tutorial](https://youtu.be/8VooYlKaqnQ), I managed to draw a [slinky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slinky).

See my `.blend` (note that I did not add the curve modifier as I want my slinky to be along an axis, see below).

[image]

Now, I'd like to animate it so I could illustrate how a [longitudinal wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_wave) propagates (as show in [this video](https://youtu.be/GIkeGBXqWW0)). For simplicity, let's consider a sinusoidal wave: the displacement field is `xi(x, t) = xi0 cos(2 pi f t - 2 pi x / lambda)` where `f` is the frequency of the wave and `lambda` is the wavelength (`lambda f = v` where `v` is the velocity of the wave).

My question is: how can I use Python to add keyframes so that the vertices of the lattice (and the slinky) are moved according to the displacement field?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that was not easy for a beginner like me but I think I found a way. Explanations about `lattice_index_from_uvw` can be found in this [question of mine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/98556/765). Just run the script once and then the handler `bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre` does the job.

```
import bpy
from math import cos

pi = 3.1415

lat = bpy.data.lattices['Lattice']
obj = bpy.data.objects['Lattice']

# Space

def lattice_index_from_uvw(lat, u, v, w):
    totu = lat.points_u
    totv = lat.points_v
    return w * (totu * totv) + (v * totu) + u

points = obj.data.points

Delta_x = points[lattice_index_from_uvw(lat, 1, 0, 0)].co_deform.x - points[lattice_index_from_uvw(lat, 0, 0, 0)].co_deform.x 

x0 = [points[lattice_index_from_uvw(lat, u, 0, 0)].co_deform.x for u in range(lat.points_u)]

A = Delta_x / 3
Lambda = 10 * Delta_x

# Time

scn = bpy.context.scene 

frame_start = scn.frame_start
frame_end = scn.frame_end

Delta_t = 1
T = frame_end - frame_start


def sine_wave(x, t, A, T, Lambda):
    return A * cos(2 * pi * ( (t / T) - (x / Lambda)))

def update_wave(t):
    for u in range(lat.points_u):
        for v in range(lat.points_v):
            for w in range(lat.points_w):
                points[lattice_index_from_uvw(lat, u, v, w)].co_deform.x = x0[u] + sine_wave(x0[u], t, A, T, Lambda)

def my_handler(scene):
    print(scene.frame_current)
    update_wave(scene.frame_current * Delta_t)

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)
```