# Show indices of vertices for a lattice

Tags: lattice

In order to solve [an other question of mine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/97506/765), I'd like to know how to adapt [this script](https://gist.github.com/zeffii/9451340) (contributed by @zeffii) in order to show (in edit mode) the indices of vertices for a lattice.

The N-panel with the `bpy.app.debug = True` trick seems to work only for meshes.

I would be curious to know if the rationale for assigning an index to a lattice vertex is [more simple than for a mesh one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36579/765).

**EDIT**

Regarding this last question, assigning an index to a lattice vertex seems to be simple. In the [source code](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/lattice.c) of blender, one can find the following:

```cpp
int BKE_lattice_index_from_uvw(Lattice *lt,
                               const int u, const int v, const int w)
{
    const int totu = lt->pntsu;
    const int totv = lt->pntsv;

    return (w * (totu * totv) + (v * totu) + u);
}

void BKE_lattice_index_to_uvw(Lattice *lt, const int index,
                              int *r_u, int *r_v, int *r_w)
{
    const int totu = lt->pntsu;
    const int totv = lt->pntsv;

    *r_u = (index % totu);
    *r_v = (index / totu) % totv;
    *r_w = (index / (totu * totv));
}
```

So it is possible to define some handy functions in Python:

```
import bpy

def lattice_index_from_uvw(lat, u, v, w):
    totu = lat.points_u
    totv = lat.points_v
    return w * (totu * totv) + (v * totu) + u

def lattice_index_to_uvw(lat, index):
    totu = lat.points_u
    totv = lat.points_v
    return (index % totu, (index // totu) % totv, (index // (totu * totv)))

lat = bpy.data.lattices['Lattice']

for w in range(lat.points_w):
    for v in range(lat.points_v):
        for u in range(lat.points_u):
            print('u = ' + str(u) + ', v = ' + str(v) + ', w = ' + str(w) + ', index:' + str(lattice_index_from_uvw(lat, u, v, w)))

for i in range(len(lat.points)):
    u, v, w = lattice_index_to_uvw(lat, i)
    print('u = ' + str(u) + ', v = ' + str(v) + ', w = ' + str(w) + ', index:' + str(i))
```