# Save Python objects in blend file?

Tags: python, animation, objects

I am [animating a scene](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/97419/765) with the help of `bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre` hook.

I'd like to be able to store the "initial state" (vertex position in this case) in some Python objects so that I can reset the animation after the changes made by the handler and even if I overwrite my `.blend` file with my "changed" scene. As a matter of fact, the next time I load my file, the initial state will be the "changed" one.

So, my question is, more or less, can I save Python objects in my `.blend` file?

Comment: [Possibly related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56993/how-can-i-export-my-blender-model-as-a-python-script) simply write vert co's  and face indices to text block.

Comment: You can use some hidden mesh objects to store vertex positions.

Comment: @lemon Great idea. Generate a duplicate of the initial state and move it to an other layer. Thanks! Would you mind turning your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @batFINGER Simple but effective! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possibility is to use some hidden mesh (or other native Blender object type) to store the wanted data.

Also, as indicated by @batFinger in comments, you can use text blocks as a more versatile solution, if needed.